# Prevent losing session while running multiple nodejs servers

Tags: node.js, firefox, session-cookies

I have two sailsjs applications running on the same machine (locally), with the first providing REST endpoints for the second. I use the same browser to interact with both the applications. The apps run on different ports.

The problem is, each time I access one application from the browser, the session for the other gets lost, requiring me to login every time I use the browser for testing the REST endpoints. I tried setting the same session secret for both application as a wild guess but it didn't work.

Is there a way to get around this?

I'm using Firefox and the applications are hosted on localhost:9999 and localhost:1337.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lets call them App A and App B. Is your Browser (C) intacting with A, or is B interacting with A? (with A being the rest api)

Comment: It's interacting with both, side by side. It loses the session for one the moment it interacts with the other, because they're both on the same domain, perhaps.

Comment: How are you storing the session? how are you passing the session id to each?

Comment: If they're on different ports, duplicate cookie names shouldn't be an issue as each will be considered a different domain, unless you're using a reverse proxy to serve them both under the same port.

Comment: I'm not doing it by hand and just letting Sails use the [default settings](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/session-js).

Comment: I'm not familiar with sails, which is why i was asking.

Comment: So, you're using a local redis installation? or am i reading that wrong.

Comment: I see. Not using redis. I'm using a mongodb collection for storing the session data.

Comment: Separate servers on separate ports have separate sets of cookies in the browser.  They cannot view or modify each other's cookies.  You could use a session ID that is returned at login and then passed with each API request afterwards.

Comment: I see. That narrows down the possible causes. I'll go experiment a little more and update if I manage to fix it.

Comment: Okay, so apparently cookies are shared across all ports so the session cookie was being overridden each time an application was being invoked. Changing the cookie name (value `key` in `config/session.js`) resolved the issue. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Sails uses the same cookie name/key ('sails.sid') for each application by default. Accessing different Sails applications made the browser override the same session cookie, leading to the described condition.

Changing the key for every application fixed the problem.

In `config/session.js`, include a `key` attribute and set it to something application-specific to avoid using `sails.sid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your session in your database, that's what `connect-mongo` does, for instance. I'm sure you can find something like that for sails too.

Comment: My issue was not with the session not being stored but the cookie being lost. If you go through the comments, you'll find I've managed to sort it by changing the cookie name for each application.